# × InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, blob

I have base64 data that i am trying convert to pdf , it is throwing below error any idea how to fix this issue ?

convertToPdf.js

```
convertToPdf(val) {
        const arrBuffer = this.base64ToArrayBuffer(val);
        const newBlob = new Blob([arrBuffer], { type: "application/pdf" });
        if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob);
            return;
        }
    
        const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
    
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(link); //required in FF, optional for Chrome
        link.href = data;
        link.download = "file.pdf";
        link.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
        link.remove();
      }
    
  
        base64ToArrayBuffer(data) {
            const binaryString = window.atob(data);
            const binaryLen = binaryString.length;
            const bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
            for (let i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
                let ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
                bytes[i] = ascii;
            }
            return bytes;
        };
```

ERROR

```
InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.
PDFEditorComponent.base64ToArrayBuffer
  39 | }
  40 | 
  41 | base64ToArrayBuffer(data) {
> 42 |   const binaryString = window.atob(data);
     | ^  43 |   const binaryLen = binaryString.length;
```

Comment: A correctly encoded base64 string allows only the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `/`, `+` and `=` (to pad the end only). Sometimes an alternate "url safe" encoding is used where `+` and `/` are replaced with `-` and `_` respectively. Is your data using the url safe version?

Comment: @CRice no data is not using url safe version this is UI where user paste the base64 and above method would download pdf

Comment: Then maybe user supplied invalid base64 string? Can you show an example of a base64 string that causes this error?